# How to change trust level for windows azure Web Site?

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, azure

I have an ASP.NET MVC 5 website hosted in the Windows Azure with a DevExpress ExportToPDF method, and it was working ok until 30/06/2014, something change in the Azure WebSite security policy.

I was researching and the developers of DevExpress said that the website now must run at `<trust level="Medium"/>`, but I changed it and I'm getting this error:

> Request for the permission of type 'System.Security.Permissions.ReflectionPermission, mscorlib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089' failed.]

How can I get the medium level in A Windows Azure website?

Comment: Why not ask Azure support?

Comment: @trailmax why not ask here too?

Comment: because nobody knows Azure better than it's support. And since something changed on the platform, they would know what have changed.

Comment: @trailmax of course they do. but a lot of users has problems with this change, so, here is a good place to find solutions for it

Comment: Not sure if it's feasible solution, but did you try deploying it as cloud service for testing and check if it works in that mode?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are several questions here.

1) Azure Web Sites always run as Full-Trust.  Therefore there should never be issues with insufficient trust level since we're running your code in the highest trust level.

2) There was a regression in Azure Web Sites (far earlier than 6/30) that would have prevent several PDF generation tools from working.  But that was fix around 6/30.  The fact that you are not seeing that is troubling as I was the one who fixed it.  So your best bet would be to either reply here or on the Azure Web Site forums with the specifics of the code you have that you expect to work.  We can then track the issue down and fix it.  Sorry for any inconvenience.

Comment: Related to this issue for me is the inability to get this package to run properly in an Azure Web App - Microsoft.ReportingServices.ReportViewerControl.Winforms.

It always fails when generating a PDF document.